Predicted estimated accumulated reward when rewards reset
I was playing a game which had an item with interesting rewards available for selection. The item maintains a counter that increases by 1 each game turn and provides a reward equal to the current value of the counter. However, this is also a 1% chance the counter can be reset each turn. I'm curious how to calculate the expected reward over time. It can't be constant since it's potentially infinite if the game has infinite turns.
Practically, I'm interested in whether it's possible to derive a function $f(N)$ where $N$ is the number of game turns that have passed that gives the estimated cumulative rewards that this item would provide over $N$ turns.
It seems straightforward that $f(1)=0.99$ and $f(2)= 0.99 + 0.99\cdot2$ but things start to be complicated with $f(3)$.



Reset on 1
Reset on 2
$f(3)$




0
1
1 + 0.99


1
0
1 + 0.99


0
0
2 + 0.99


1
1
0.99



I'm not really sure where to go from here. Any thoughts appreciated.
EDIT
To clarify, you accumulate winnings on each game turn and taking the winnings does not reset the counter. So lets say during five game turns, the counter only resets on turn 4. This gives the counter sequence 1, 2, 3, 0, 1 with a total reward of 7.

Not sure the rules are clear.  Specifically, this seems strategy dependent.  As I understand it (possibly incorrectly) I can take the prize whenever I like. If I pass on some turn, then either the value drops to $0$ or it goes up $1$ (with known probabilities).  But...when should I take it?  If I am infinitely patient, I'll eventually see a very high value, right?  Of course, that's not a practical strategy if my threshold is so high that it will take a million years to reach.  So..what strategy did you have in mind?

Just for clarify the rules. Say that the counter sequence is $1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1$, since you hit the $1%$ reset at turn $5$, and you decide to stop. How much you win? Just $1$, as the current counter value, or $11$, the sum of the counter values so far?

To clarify, you always take the prize at every step of the game and the counter state does not reset when you take the prize. This isn't a push your luck sort of situation.

With the problem stated this way, at any point in time $t$ it's hardly relevant to look behind for the whole history of the process. What matters is the last non-zero sequence of counters which practically form the Negative Binomial distribution:
$$
Pr(X=k) = p^k (1-p)
$$
The expected length of such sequences:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] 
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp^k (1-p) 
= p (1-p) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp^{k-1}
= p (1-p) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial p} {p^{k}}
= p (1-p) \frac{\partial}{\partial p} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{p^{k}}
= p (1-p) \frac{\partial}{\partial p} \frac{1}{1-p}
= p (1-p) \frac{1}{(1-p)^2} = \frac{p}{1-p}
$$
In your case that would give the constant value of 99 units of the reward.


For how I understood the rules, you win the counter value at each turn and can accumulate. Say that the counter sequence is $1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1$ (at the fifth turn you hit the 1% reset), you win 11. Not sure if I'm correct though

@nicola You are indeed correct. You win the value every turn and taking the winnings does not reset the counter.

@Egor I think I didn't do the best job of explaining how the rewards are earned. See my edit.
